# Google Map API - float div on top

Tags: css, google-maps

I am having issues getting a div to display on top of a Google Map API block.

As far as I can see I have it positioned absolute with a z-index which should place it on top, but I don't see it.  It is the .topblock1 div I am looking to appear over the map.

```
<div class="block4">


                <div id="map-canvas"> 
                        <div class="topblock1">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit. Morbi risus sapien.</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit. Morbi risus sapien.</p>
                        <a href="#PROJECTS">SEE OUR CURRENT PROJECTS >></a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar code, try closing your map-canvas div first:

```
<div class="block4">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div class="topblock1">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit. Morbi risus sapien.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit. Morbi risus sapien.</p>
        <a href="#PROJECTS">SEE OUR CURRENT PROJECTS >></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper around the map canvas, the code of google hide all elemets that are not native.

```
         <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="topblock1">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit. Morbi risus sapien.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit. Morbi risus sapien.</p>
             <a href="#PROJECTS">SEE OUR CURRENT PROJECTS >></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
         <div id="map-canvas">            
         </div>
         </div>
```

And set this css

```
         <style>
            .wrapper{ display:block; position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; right: 0px;}
            .topblock1{ display:block; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right: 0px; z-index:99999} /* Must be above map-canvas */
         </style>
```